# How to find continuous and differentiable function based on a piecewise composition and drawing

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

> Let $f(x) = (x - k)^2$ and $g(x)$ is below:
>   [image]
>
> Find $k$ such that $f(g(x))$ is continuous and differentiable for all $x$.

The $g(x)$ is:
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases} \pi \quad x \ge 2 \\
2 \quad x <2
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f(g(x))$ is:
$$
f(g(x)) = \begin{cases} (\pi-k)^2 \quad x \ge 2 \\
(2-k)^2 \quad x <2
\end{cases}
$$
After equating $(\pi-k)^2$ and $(2-k)^2$ I found $k = \frac{\pi-2}{2}$. According to my calculations this ensures continuity.

For it to be differentiable the one-sided limits of the function's derivative need to equal but differentiating constants should be $0$ so we should be fine because both parts of $f(g(x))$ are constants and their derivative and limit should be zero. Yet the correct answer is $1+\frac{\pi}{2}$.

What's wrong in my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a mistake there:
$(\pi -k)^{2}=(2 -k)^{2}\Rightarrow $
i) $\pi-k=2-k$, which implies $\pi=2$, false
ii)$\pi-k=k-2$, hence $2k=\pi+2\Rightarrow k=1+\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning is right; your algebra is wrong. For the equation
$(\pi-k)^2 = (2-k)^2$, take square roots of both sides *carefully*, allowing for plus or minus. One of those possibilities leads to an immediate contradiction. The other yields the correct solution.